# Automatically Ignore @OneToMany, @ManyToOne

Tags: javers

I'm successfully logging entities with Javers, but for every entity I have to put @DiffIgnore and @ShallowReference to ignore fields mapped with @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, etc. 
I'm trying to configure on JaversBuilder, but without success.
Is there a way to configure on Javers to automatically ignore properties mapped with these annotation? Or only take properties with @Column annotation?

I read these, and tried to follow some of the answers, but it didn't worked either.

[Javers - DiffIgnore on bidirectional OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263340/javers-diffignore-on-bidirectional-onetomany)

[Javers default ignore instead of default include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317181/javers-default-ignore-instead-of-default-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to order JaVers to ignore a field when it has a specific annotation. JaVers doesn't read all annotations in your classes.

You can implement a annotation scanner on your side and then register your EntityDefinitions in JaversBuilder:

`public JaversBuilder registerEntity(EntityDefinition entityDefinition)`

Comment: Thanks, but from what I see, I'll have to do it for every entity, and I'm already doing it, using the DiffIgnore and ShallowReference annotations.
The advantage is that i can do some code to do it automatically using this entity definition.
But anyway, thanks for the answer.